# Copypaste doesn't work properly sometimes while XCUITest running. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcuitest

When the issue happens I see `CoreSimulatorBridge pasted from CoreSimulatorBridge` popup instead of my usual popup `MyApp pasted from MyAppUITests-Runner`. Any comments why it could happen?
code example:

```
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "build 2882"

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let textField = app.textFields["my text field"]
    textField.tap()
    let menuQuery = app.menuItems 
    let menuItem = menuQuery["Paste"]
    menuItem.waitForExistence(timeout: 5)
    menuItem.tap()
```

The rare result:
[image]

Comment: How are you copy and pasting? Please share your code.

Comment: @MikeCollins thank you for asking. I have updated my post with this info.

Comment: I don't have a handy way to test this at the moment, but I know in my code I hit the menu items as staticTexts instead of menuItems. Seems unlikely to be the problem, but worth a try?